# How can I enable the use of multiple discount codes on one purchase?

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, discounts

I have a group of customers who are eligible for discounts - 20% off one type of product and 40% off another.
The problem is that they will sometimes want to order both types of product in the same order.

I can only seem to be able to apply one discount code at the checkout. Does anybody know how I can enable the use of multiple discount codes, for different product types, at the checkout?

We are using the Craft Commerce plugin

Comment: Hi there, welcome to Craft.SE! Are you using the Craft Commerce plugin? If so, you may want to mention that, and/or add the `plugin-craftcommerce` tag.